How to execute a java class with Redis Gears
I've followed the instructions on the quick start running a java redis gears to execute a java class however when I come to execute the class I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException.
Here is what I've tried

Created a docker container from image redislabs/redisgears:latest
Created a simple java project using JDK 11 and generated a jar with a Main class

package com.example;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello world!");
   }
}


The folder containing the jar is mounted as a volume in the container at /app
I start the container and it confirms that gears and the JVM module are present

redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.086 # <rg> Loading plugin GearsJVMPlugin version 999999 
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.086 * <module> JVM Options: -Xrs
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.086 * <module> JVM Options: -Djava.class.path=/var/opt/redislabs/modules/rg/gear_runtime-jar-with-dependencies.jar
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.086 * <module> Loading jvm from /var/opt/redislabs/modules/rg/OpenJDK/jdk-11.0.9.1+1//lib/server/libjvm.so
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.125 * <rg> Executing : mkdir -p /data/-jars
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.126 * <rg> Executing : rm -rf /data/-jars/*
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * Module 'rg' loaded from /var/opt/redislabs/lib/modules/redisgears.so
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.5
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * RDB age 3 seconds
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * RDB memory usage when created 8.76 Mb
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis-gears_1  | 1:M 15 May 2024 13:14:00.127 * Ready to accept connections


I then connect to redis using a redis client and execute

RG.JEXECUTE com.example.Main /app/redis-gears-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar


The output is an error with the ClassNotFoundException

Connecting to the container I can see that every time I issue the RG.JEXECUTE command it creates a new file in /data/-jars which I assume is a copy of my jar. However it does not have the same checksum as my jar and when I try to list the contents of it using jar -tf it complains that it is not a valid jar file.
Note that I've also tried
RG.JEXECUTE com.example.Main < /path/to/jar/on/local/file/system/redis-gears-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

But this still results in error.
I've also tried executing the class manually from within the container with the JDK present in the redisgears module like this and it works.
root@805cdbf8f2c3:/data# /var/opt/redislabs/modules/rg/OpenJDK/jdk-11.0.9.1+1/bin/java -cp /app/redis-gears-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.Main
Hello world!

What am I missing or is this a bug?
